# mvc 2 jsonresult output

Tags: json, model-view-controller, jsonresult

how can i see the raw json output of mvc 2 jsonresult? i need this to enable me debug the results.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.  If you are servicing a GET request, you can just navigate to a url that will return your JSON in the browser.  I like to use the JSON View plugin for firefox for this purpose:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10869/

If you are would like to debug this during an ajax request, I suggest using the firebug plugin for firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/

The 'net' tab will allow you to see all http requests go by as they are made.  You can then click the 'json' tab to view the output.